# How to count items in a dict and filter based on item ID?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I am querying the following dict that uses Users and Groups from Django contrib auth:

In `views.py` I pass the following as context to the template:

```
group_user_dict = {group: group.user_set.all() for 
    group in Group.objects.all().order_by('id')}
```

It's then easy enough to loop through all the items:

```
{% for group, users in group_user_dict.items %}
   {{ group.id }}: {{ group.name }}
   {% for i in users %} 
       {{ i.get_full_name }} 
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

However, how can I:

1. Count the number of users in each group and display this in the template? E.g. `{{ group.users_set.count() }}`
2. display just the results from the first, second, third (etc...) group? E.g. `Group 1 ID, Group 1 name: Users in group 1 only`.

Comment: I'm not understanding your 2nd question, can you clarify it a little bit please.

Comment: @Hagyn For example, I just want to display users in the second group. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `{{ users.count }}` for the first question.

For displaying users in group 2 for example it would be `{{ for user_of_group_2 in group_user_dict.values.1 }}`.

For counting the list of groups it would be `{{ group_user_dict.keys|length }}`.

If you do not understand some feel free to ask.

Comment: thanks, how would I count the groups? {{ group.count }} does not appear to display anything.